# Is there a wait function in C++?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, wait

I have been working on a program, and it makes use of the sleep() function. I want it to be cross platform for macOS, Linux, and Windows but having three branches is tedious to work with and is terrible to do. What can I do to make it cross platform? And what functions that make the program wait for a few seconds work? When I test it, it doesn’t even work...

Linux code doesn’t seem to work...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;


int loading() {
  sleep(0.25);
  cout << "Loading... ";
  sleep(0.25);
  cout << "hi";
  sleep(0.25);
  cout << "e";
  sleep(0.25);
  return 0;
}
int main() {
  loading();
  return 0;
}
```

Neither does Windows...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


int loading() {
  Sleep(250);
  cout << "Loading... ";
  Sleep(250);
  cout << "hi";
  Sleep(250);
  cout << "e";
  Sleep(250);
  return 0;
}
int main() {
  loading();
  return 0;
}
```

Is the syntax wrong, or am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Unix sleep uses seconds, while windows Sleep milliseconds. Different APIs, different behaviors.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since C++11, you might use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::this_thread::sleep_for(250ms);
```

Comment: It’s cross-platform right? And will it have any dependencies?

Comment: @Amatsuki555 It's more than cross-platform -- it is standard C++.

Comment: @Amatsuki555, It's part of the standard library. Any standard compliant compiler (since C++11) will support it.

Comment: Oh... I was just making sure because I’m pretty new to C++

Comment: @Amatsuki555 -- Since C++11, threads, synchronization, timers, etc. were added to the C++ language library. You may want to get a good book that is geared toward C++ 11 (not pre-C++11).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a simpler method still using Sleep_for:

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main(){

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

}
```

usually always works for me, you can also change from seconds to milliseconds, ecc...

Comment: How does this improve on the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67320299/10871073), posted some years ago?